# Installing pylint OSX omits executable

Tags: macos, installation, pylint

Today I installed pylint on OSX (Python 2.7 Homebrew , pip 7.1.2). The pylint executable was nowhere to be found. In ended up copying the file from Github, pasting to /usr/local/bin, and making it executable, which seems to solve the issue.

I am fairly new to OSX, why would pip not install the executable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's much probably a bug. You  should open an issue on pylint's tracker at https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add path info to ~/.profile.  Here's what I added:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

You can run `vi ~/.profile` from the terminal window to edit.  Use 'i' to insert the lines.  'ESC' to halt insertion.  ':x!' to save.

From the command line, run `source ~/.profile` for things to update